# ID Column not updating while other columns are?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Good day.

This slight error has been bugging me for a bit and I can't seem to find what's the problem. There a 3 columns: id, last_name and first_name. The latter 2 update just fine but the id column keeps reverting back to its original value.

Ok, so here's some snippets of my code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name ='doc_list[]' value =". $row ."></input></td>
          <td><input type='text' maxlength='9' id='id' name ='id' value =". $row['id'] ."></input></td> 
          <td><input type='text' maxlength='32' id='last_name' name ='last_name' value =". $row['last_name'] ."></input></td>
          <td><input type='text' maxlength='32' id='first_name' name ='first_name' value =". $row['first_name'] ."></input></td>
          <td><input type='submit' value='Update'/></td>
          <td><div id='message'></div></td>";

}
```

Then when the form submits:

```
//Extracts the information from the form
$id = clean($_POST['id']);
$first_name = clean($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = clean($_POST['last_name']);

//Input validations
//include("../php/validate_insertion.php");


//Updates doctor info
$query1="UPDATE doctors 
     SET id= '$id', last_name='$last_name', first_name='$first_name'
     WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
```

Where's the error?

Comment: Why are you changing the id in your database. that's your primary key, you need that so you can call the data with the corresponding id.  If you need something like to show what is the latest updated data then you can create another field like 'modified'.

Comment: No problem. just create another unique table, I always add created and modified (date and time), so you can get the data base on the latest or the updated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get the logic of changing the ID, but the problem is that you are not conserving the original id. You need that in the `where` condition to update the original record, not the record that happens to have the new ID as well.

If you really want to go this way (you'll run into trouble if there are duplicate ids...), you should add the original ID as a hidden field so that you know which record to update.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the mention that the first snippet is reading from the sql database. The second is writing to it. Also, where did I change the id?

Comment: @Megakeemo I figured as much, but updating an ID where ID=ID will never do anything.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh. I see what you're saying now. Haha, thanks much. I fixed it now. Sometimes an extra set of eyes can go a loooong way.

Comment: @Megakeemo By the way, if there is more than 1 result from your database query, you will be overwriting your form fields as you will have multiple inputs with the same name. You can solve that converting them to arrays: `name='id[{$row['id']}]'`

Comment: Does the name matter so much as the value?

Comment: @Megakeemo More I would say, you will only have the value of the last ID in `$_POST['id']` if you have multiple inputs with the name `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you changing id is my first question.

In any case if you really need to change id, you will have to get hold of original id for which this form was generated. One way of doing this is to put a hidden input field in the form which can give you the original id of the db row for which this form was generated.

PS: Also from security perspective it's not a great idea to accept id from a user form, depending upon which you are going to update the row. What if someone change that hidden field id to something else.

Comment: So what other methods are there to get the ID then?

Comment: At the simplest you can follow hash-hmac strategy to ensure you get what you expect from the form and catch any possible attempt to crack the form. One short usage can be found here... http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/12/how-to-add-content-verification-using-hmac-in-php/